# ReactJS. Не обновляется состояния из свойств при ре-рендере

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Простой пример :

```
class Element extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: props.name
        }
    }
    render() {
        return <p>{this.state.name}</p>
    }
}

class Elements extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            names: props.names
        }
    }
    render() {
        return <div>{
            this.state.names.map(function(name, i) {
                return <Element key={ i } name={ name } />
            })  
        }</div>
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        setTimeout(
            () => {
                this.state.names.splice(1, 1);
                let names = this.state.names;
                this.setState({names: names});
            },
            3000
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Elements names={ [0, 1, 2] } />,
    document.body
);
```

Вообщем, создаем **Element**. Он в свойствах принимает *name*. Пишем *name* в состояние *name*. И выводим состояние *name*.

**Elements** принимает в свойства *names* - массив *name* для **Element**. *names* пишет в свое состояние *names*. Проходит в выводе состояние *names* и для каждого создает **Element**, передавая очередной *name* в свойства ему.

Дальше setTimeout - просто для примера, неважно как, но состояние *names* у **Elements** меняется. Удаляется какой-либо *name* из него. В итоге все **Element** перерисовываются и у каждого нужное свойство *name*. А вот состояние *name* не изменяется.

Стал проверять - да, **constructor** не срабатывает, когда **Element** перерисовывается. **ComponentWillMount** тоже. **ComponentWillUnmount** срабатывает для одного элемента, но не для того, который удалили, а для последнего почему-то.

Короче в итоге все выглядит так : Сначала на мониторе **0 1 2** , а затем **0 1** . А должно быть **0 2** .

Ни как не могу понять, почему так происходит...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все дело в атрибуте key для **Element** :

```
render() {
    return <div>{
        this.state.names.map(function(name, i) {
            return <Element key={ i } name={ name } />
        })  
    }</div>
}
```

*key* должен быть уникальным для родственных итерируемых элементов. Здесь *key* - это индекс массива.

Элемент из массива удаляется, а индекс его остается и добавляется в *key* другого элемента. Из за этого **React** определяет такой элемент, как тот, который уже удалили.

Answer (score 1):

Да, Вы правильно определили "физический" источник проблемы, но я не уверен что Вы поняли какая плохая практика к этому привела.

Вот эта:

```
this.state.names.splice(1, 1);
```

**Менять state напрямую нельзя.**

```
this.state.smth = smthelse; // не надо так

this.setState({ //надо так
   smth: smthelse
})
```

Со стейтом стоит вести себя так, именно за счет того чтобы изменения стейта не конфликтовали с внутренними механизмами реакта.
В документации об этом кстати тоже [говорят:](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html)

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

В вашем примере попробуйте что-то подобное:

```
let newNames = [...this.state.names.slice(0,1), ...this.state.names.slice(2)];
this.setState({
   names: newNames
});
```

**Больше примеров** как вести себя с массивами как с иммутабельными "из коробки" [тут](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread).

**Также** при работе в react-redux зачастую [пользуются библиотеками которые предоставляют иммутабельные структуры из коробки](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html), например [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

**Про физический смысл key.** Перестройка virtual dom, это в общем случае операция сложности O(n^3). Что для всяких списков - очень долго. Вот указание key - это способ сказать что полная перестройка по факту не нужна (большинство практических случаев), и уменьшить сложность этой операции до O(n). Ну то есть key нужен, без него бывают шансы нарваться на тупняки на ровном месте.