# Не могу понять почему в консоли react пишет ошибку

Tags: reactjs

файл где пишет ошибку ItemUrgency:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
Button
} from 'reactstrap';
//import views
import DeleteProblem from '../Modals/DeleteProblem';

export default class ItemUrgency extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        editing: false,
        urgency: this.props.urgency
    };
}

handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
        editing: !this.state.editing
    });
};

render(){
    return(
        <tr>
            {!this.state.editing ? [
                <td>{this.props.urgency.problem}</td>,
                <td>{this.props.urgency.time}</td>,
                <td className='text-center'>
                    <Button color='primary' onClick={this.handleClick}>редактировать</Button>
                </td>
            ] : [
                <td><input className='form-control' type='text' value={this.props.urgency.problem}/></td>,
                <td><input className='form-control' type='text' value={this.props.urgency.time}/></td>,
                <td className='text-center'>
                    <Button color='success' onClick={this.handleClick}>сохранить</Button>
                </td>
            ]}
            <td className='text-right'>
                <DeleteProblem/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
}
}
```

файл где происходит итерация и по идеи  должен быть ключ ItemsUrgency:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

//import views
import ItemUrgency from './ItemUrgency';


export default class ItemsUrgency extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        editing: false,
        urgency: this.props.urgency
    };
}
static propTypes = {
    urgency: PropTypes.array
};

handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
        editing: !this.state.editing
    });
};

render(){
    return(
        <tbody>
            {this.state.urgency.map((item) =>
                <ItemUrgency key={item.item} urgency={item} />
            )}
        </tbody>
    );
}
}
```

сама ошибка:
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `ItemUrgency`. See https://fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.

Comment: посмотрите вот этот ответ, самый конец: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589559/reactjs-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5/589818#589818

Comment: Он понятным англйским языком говорит, что если Вы пытаетесь отрендерить массив (массив тдшек в вашем случае) будет весьма полезно назначить каждом элементу ключ чтобы это шустрее работало когда этот массив придется перерендерить. Это дело добровольное и здесь врядли приведет к проблемам с производительностью. Но в больших списках рекомендую ключ таки назначать

Answer (score 1):

Читайте ответ [здесь](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are
>   removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give
>   the elements a stable identity:

*(перевод)*

***keys** помогают React определить, какие элементы были изменены, добавлены или удалены. **keys** должны быть даны элементам в массиве, чтобы обеспечить уникальность элементов:*

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
  <li key={number.toString()}>
    {number}
  </li>
);
```

> The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies
>   a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your
>   data as keys:

*(перевод)*

*Лучший способ выбрать **key** - использовать строку, которая однозначно идентифицирует элемент списка среди остальных. Чаще всего используются идентификаторы из Ваших данных в качестве ключей:*

```
const todoItems = todos.map((todo) =>
  <li key={todo.id}>
    {todo.text}
  </li>
);
```